# How can I change a connection string, or other app settings, at test time in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, configuration

I need to test a class library project in VS. This project, itself, does not have a web.config file, but the classes do on the web server to which it's deployed. I access these like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stringname"].ConnectionString;
```

Can I adjust these strings while running unit tests in VS? Should I have considered a different design method to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the configuration into the app.config of the unit test project.

Comment: figured it was easy--just didn't know what to call it. thanks